# Changing Layer CRS Causes Misalignment and Scaling Issues

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

#### Update:

My final solution was to re-download the data sets and all my alignment issues were solved.

#### Background:

I am working on a personal project overlaying the location of churches/parishes on various counties in New Jersey. The parishes are contained in a .geojson file and the state counties come from a shapefile provided by the state.

#### Problem:

When both layers are loaded the parish layer is way up to the left of the counties and both have different CRSs. The parish is EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 while the counties are the same as the project crs EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. When I change the crs of the parish layer to the projects there are alignment issues and scale issues. The parishes are much closer (but still not over the counties) and to the bottom left. Further the scaling goes wrong and all the data points are much to close to each other.

How do I resolve this alignment issue?

The final result is I will be making a map to print out, which I can do now my manual exporting the layers at a fixed scale. Then I can manually align the two exports in my image editing software. I would prefer to figure out this issue mainly to learn more about these things.

#### Key Information and Links:

Parish Layer CRS: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84
Project CRS: EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator

Base data source comes from State of New Jersey - GIS Open Data State Counties.
Link Here:
https://njogis-newjersey.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5f45e1ece6e14ef5866974a7b57d3b95_1/geoservice?geometry=-78.816%2C39.583%2C-70.472%2C41.049

I made the parish data source using geojson.io. You can view the data source one either:
GitHub: https://github.com/pulsence/diocese-of-metuchen-parish-map or
GeoJson: http://geojson.io/#id=github:pulsence/diocese-of-metuchen-parish-map/blob/master/parish%20locations.geojson&map=10/40.6289/-74.7065

I am using for this project QGIS 3.0.3-Girona.

Comment: The counties are not EPSG:3857, but EPSG:4326 as well (or NAD83). Both fit to an OSM background in QGIS 2.18. There might have been a bug in QGIS 3.0.3, so I suggest to update to QGIS 3.2.3.

Comment: Ok, so I went and played around with the CRSs after updating to the latest QGIS 3.2.3. I made all the layers and the project EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 and different combinations. The consistent issue is that the counties layer and parish layer are not lining up. I have both layers visible at the same time, however I would have expected the two layers to actually over lap. Even more interesting, I added an OSM background and with everything is EPSG:4326 the counties are over Nigeria and parishes are in the Atlantic off the coast of Nigeria.

Comment: I think your basic error is to use `Set Layer CRS` assuming it would reproject your data.Unless you requested the county layer in EPSG:3857, it is EPSG:4326 by default. Let both layers in their native projection, and set the project CRS to 3857, then add an OSM basemap.

Comment: I get that. The only way I get the parish layer to line up on the OSM is by the two CRSs (project and layer) being different. With the counties at the native CRS they don't appear on the OSM for me, but when I Zoom To Layer for the counties I go to the middle of the OSM map, Nigeria. Sorry if that's not the most clear.

Comment: Can you post the extent of the counties layer, as reported in the layers properties, metadata tab?

Comment: Calculated from current:layer, North: 5008031.6746, East: -8262329.1963, South: 4907474.5837, West: -8370250.5171

Comment: I suggest to download the county data again, they offer a download link for shapefile format, and under the API dropdown, there is a geojson downlad as well.

Comment: I've downloaded everything again, paying attention to the CRS and have everything lining up properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to re-download the data sets and then the alignment issues were solved. I do not know what caused the issue in the first place.